# NodeJS URL content send

Tags: web

I create a NodeJS and try to send the content of a URL as the body of a response. The server.js file is below. Can you help me?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('https://http.cat/200').end();
});

// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Importing Libs
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

// Init express
const app = express();

// Initial constants
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/cat.html'));
});

// Listening for clients
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Comment: I wish to show the "cat" webpage 'https://http.cat/200' and not the url text as shows on https://primeiro-servidor.rj.r.appspot.com/.

Comment: Then, you can use res.sendFile('C:/Users/...../cat.html') to serve the desired source.html.    And you can use app.get('/*', (req, res)) in order to match all your routes to the root

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is the whole project: https://github.com/brunolnetto/first_app . The index page is is on folder /public , but after deploy, only "Not Found" appears

Comment: I solved your problem, I put it at [my repo](https://github.com/VictorMfr/Stackoverflow-collab)